# How to call Stored Procedure asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous

In my **ASP.NET MVC (C#)** application, i am using **Entity Framework** and calling Stored Procudures like this :

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<ART_USP_GetAssetReportGridList_Result> ART_USP_GetAssetReportGridList(string searchExpression, string sortExpression, string sortDirection, Nullable<int> startIndex, Nullable<int> pageSize, ObjectParameter count)
    {
        var searchExpressionParameter = searchExpression != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("SearchExpression", searchExpression) :
            new ObjectParameter("SearchExpression", typeof(string));

        var sortExpressionParameter = sortExpression != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("SortExpression", sortExpression) :
            new ObjectParameter("SortExpression", typeof(string));

        var sortDirectionParameter = sortDirection != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("SortDirection", sortDirection) :
            new ObjectParameter("SortDirection", typeof(string));

        var startIndexParameter = startIndex.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("StartIndex", startIndex) :
            new ObjectParameter("StartIndex", typeof(int));

        var pageSizeParameter = pageSize.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("PageSize", pageSize) :
            new ObjectParameter("PageSize", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<ART_USP_GetAssetReportGridList_Result>("ART_USP_GetAssetReportGridList", searchExpressionParameter, sortExpressionParameter, sortDirectionParameter, startIndexParameter, pageSizeParameter, count);
    }
```

Here **ART_USP_GetAssetReportGridList** is the stored procedure name. This is a synchronous call. If the number of records are more than 3000 this call is giving me Time-out error.

How can i make this call asynchronously without getting the Time-out error?

Comment: Dont allow more than 100 records (pageSize) per sql round trip. The solution is not to async call sp, it is to benefit from the paging mechanism you already have.

Comment: Paging mechanism is used while binding the records onto a gridview. But i am using the same method for exporting to excel also. For that the page size will be the total records, I cannot limit the call with page size in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may increase the timeout on specific operations as follows.

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180; // in sec
```

Or set this code on your DbContext constructor.

Comment: Wow..wow..wow..Its working like a charm @Houssam Hamdan. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Calling this asyncronously wont make any difference. You are getting a command timeout error. I order to avoid this you should increase the CommandTimeout setting of the SQL connection. But I would very much recommend not doing this, and looking at your stored procedure efficiency - the 30 second default timeout should be way, way more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 var data = ObjectContext.Database.SqlQuery<ART_USP_GetAssetReportGridList_Result>("ART_USP_GetAssetReportGridList", searchExpressionParameter, sortExpressionParameter, sortDirectionParameter, startIndexParameter, pageSizeParameter, count).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: **FirstOrDefaultAsync** will return only the first element in the sequence. Also this line has some compilation errors as per the structure of my method.